# Sound not working from backup (wsl)

Tags: pulseaudio, backup, windows-subsystem-for-linux

This is the output from `pulseaudio -v`.

It contains information about what may be essential to solve the problem 'no sound after restoring backup with wsl'. It seems that there is some connection problems and that the system can't find the soundcard (although it has been working before the backup and that is was present in qasmixer).

The previous text has been replaced with this one. Can anyone help?

```
 stone    Desktop  ﮫ0ms⠀   pulseaudio -v
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 13.99.1
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is ea1741854df741aaa37d3ce37f4c1740.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using runtime directory /etc/xdg/mytmpdir/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using state directory /home/stone/.config/pulse.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Using modules directory /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1/modules.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in system mode: no
W: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Stale PID file, overwriting.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: System supports high resolution timers
I: [pulseaudio] cpu-x86.c: CPU flags: CMOV MMX SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 MMXEXT 
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_mmx.c: Initialising MMX optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] remap_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized remappers.
I: [pulseaudio] sconv_sse.c: Initialising SSE2 optimized conversions.
I: [pulseaudio] svolume_orc.c: Initialising ORC optimized volume functions.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/stone/.config/pulse/ea1741854df741aaa37d3ce37f4c1740-device-volumes'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-device-restore" (index: #0; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-stream-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/stone/.config/pulse/ea1741854df741aaa37d3ce37f4c1740-stream-volumes'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-stream-restore" (index: #1; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-card-restore.c: Successfully opened database file '/home/stone/.config/pulse/ea1741854df741aaa37d3ce37f4c1740-card-database'.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-card-restore" (index: #2; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-augment-properties" (index: #3; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-port-available" (index: #4; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-switch-on-connect" (index: #5; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Found 0 cards.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-udev-detect" (index: #6; argument: "").
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/home/stone/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authentication key '/home/stone/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to open cookie file '/home/stone/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
W: [pulseaudio] authkey.c: Failed to load authentication key '/home/stone/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-native-protocol-unix" (index: #7; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-default-device-restore" (index: #8; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c: Created sink 0 "auto_null" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.description = "Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.class = "abstract"
I: [pulseaudio] sink.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c: Created source 0 "auto_null.monitor" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.class = "monitor"
I: [pulseaudio] source.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
I: [null-sink] util.c: Successfully enabled SCHED_RR scheduling for thread, with priority 5.
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_source: (unset) -> auto_null.monitor
I: [pulseaudio] core.c: default_sink: (unset) -> auto_null
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-null-sink" (index: #10; argument: "sink_name=auto_null sink_properties='device.description="Dummy Output"'").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-always-sink" (index: #9; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-intended-roles" (index: #11; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-suspend-on-idle" (index: #12; argument: "").
E: [pulseaudio] module-console-kit.c: Unable to contact D-Bus system bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.FileNotFound: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-console-kit" (argument: ""): initialization failed.
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-systemd-login" (index: #14; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #15; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-role-cork" (index: #16; argument: "").
I: [snapd-glib] module-snap-policy.c: Starting GLib main loop
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-snap-policy" (index: #17; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-heuristics" (index: #18; argument: "").
I: [pulseaudio] module.c: Loaded "module-filter-apply" (index: #19; argument: "").
W: [pulseaudio] server-lookup.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.BadAddress: '=' character not found or has no value following it
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.BadAddress: '=' character not found or has no value following it
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup complete.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Storing port for device sink:auto_null.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Storing volume/mute for device+port sink:auto_null:null.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Storing port for device source:auto_null.monitor.
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Storing volume/mute for device+port source:auto_null.monitor:null.
I: [pulseaudio] module-suspend-on-idle.c: Sink auto_null idle for too long, suspending ...
I: [pulseaudio] module-device-restore.c: Synced.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  Can you provide some more details?  Edit your question so that everyone can see the updates clearly -- (1) What exactly did you restore from backup?  Windows?  A WSL export?  Something else? (2) What version of Windows are you running?  PulseAudio is only directly supported by Windows 11.  If you are on Windows 10, it can be done, but what process did you use?

Comment: I restored Ubuntu 20.04 from a backup in a Windows folder. I used the powershell command wsl export to save the file and wsl import to restore the distro. Before that the current version was deleted. I am running Windows 11. I wonder if another instance of pulse deamon is running and that is the reason for the connection issue.I restored distro 20.04 from a backup in a Windows folder. I used the powershell command wsl export to save the file and wsl import to restore the distro. Before that the current version was deleted. I am running Windows 11.

Comment: The way I understand it, under Windows 11, PulseAudio actually isn't running in your Ubuntu instance itself.  It's part of WSLg, which is a "hidden", system distribution from Microsoft.  The PulseAudio socket is linked into your Ubuntu distribution by the WSL `/init` process.  Which makes me wonder -- Perhaps the `--export`/`--import` process is corrupting that link somehow.  Let me think on that a bit ...

Comment: You had an "answer", I believe, that should have been part of the question.  It's been deleted, but it probably still shows up for you (and users with more rep than I have).  Could you edit the question to add that additional detail?  Thanks!